In Microsoft Teams, how to share only audio without screen share?
When joining calls in MS teams, others teams will be doing the presentation. Once a presentation is done, I need to play a small audio clip. However, I won't be sharing the screen.
How to share only audio from my computer without sharing the screen?

Make a very small keynote presentation with a black background and share that window. Try minimizing the window if you like once you’re sharing audio.
If you can run a Teams Live Event or Town Hall you can have more control over audio only sharing.

I can't share any window as other people are sharing their screen already. Cant use Live Event or Town Hall at the moment.

You’re out of luck with MS, then @ChillarAnand . You need something like OBS to mix things as you require, not Teams. Why not change your teams to music mode and play the sound from speakers or a tablet or phone close to your mic?
